# Detect Two finger touch on UIIMageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multi-touch

I am trying to detect two finger touch on a UIImageView object. In xib I had set multi-touch enbled.
Then I implemented the following code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //NSLog(@"%@", [[touches anyObject] class]);
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"%@", [touch class]);
    if ([touches count] > 1)
        NSLog(@"multi touches: %d fingers", [touches count]);

    NSUInteger numTaps = [touch tapCount];

    if (numTaps == 1) {
        NSLog(@"single tap");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"multi tap: %d", numTaps);
    }
}
```

What actually happning with this code is: This is detecting multiple taps not multi-touch. How can I detect that user touched on object with two finger(Multi-Touch).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use gestureRecognizers like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleFingerTap:)];
twoFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[super addGestureRecognizers:twoFingerTap];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Comment: This is not working on UIIMageView when I try to add on it. This works well on my View. Can I use it on ImageView object..?

Comment: Or can I detect the touch points so I can check if touch happens in the Image Area..?

Comment: Create a customView class and add imageView to cover it.

Comment: addGestureRecognizer, NOT 'addGestureRecognizers'

Comment: This "numberOfTouchesRequired" means either a single tap or double tap. i

Answer (score 0):

At this point you are really better off using a gesture recognizer, looking for two taps with two fingers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event object for the same as

```
 NSSet *touch = [event allTouches];
 int touchCounts = [touch count];
 if(touchCounts >2)
 {
 //Multitouch.
 }
```